# How do I choose what horse I spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

There are summon commands for mobs in Minecraft, ie;  `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:4,Tame:1}` Summons a Tamed Skeleton horse with full health.

### So my real question here is:

- What are the specifics for spawning Horses?
- Is there a way of choosing the exact colors and health amount?

  - For example: how would you spawn a brown horse with white spots and 14 health?

**Or** just whether or not something like that is possible?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade SOLIDShift! I edited your post to make the question stand out more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The full list of mob attributes (including horse-specific attributes) can be found [on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Mobs). For your particular example, you need 'Variant' and 'Health', e.g.:

```
{Variant:515,Health:28,Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:28}],Tame:1,Saddle:true}
```

Health is current number of half-hearts. The maxHealth attribute is the max number of half-hearts.

Variant is calculated as base-color-id + markings-id * 256, that is, 515 = 2 * 256 + 3 means base-color-id = 3 and markings-id = 2

Comment: I took a while to try this and unfortunately it wasn't working.

Comment: @SOLIDShift Please, describe in more detail the 'not working' part - what exactly happens after you issue the command?

Comment: Ah! Well one three things may happen;; **o1**. It doesn't fit the entire command do to character limitations.  **o2**. It'll inform me that it doesn't understand a certain parts of the code, specifically, the [{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:28}] part. o3. It'll just spawn a random horse. ((_but I feel this all may be because I haven't tried it using the command block yet because I forgot about it_))

Comment: @SOLIDShift Yes, character limitations can be annoying, try using command blocks. If you see error message for the command, you need to look very carefully at the punctuation, as it is important. Paste the command and the exact error message here so we can help. If the game spawns a random horse, this still suggests there is an error in the command syntax. Paste the command and describe exactly what you are trying to spawn and what is spawned instead.

Comment: :: It works! That Command black is one fancy little Block. I was about to spawn any horse type, color, and health after messing around with it. Thanks so much, good sir!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an updated answer to the same question.  Currently Minecraft is version 1.12.1.

To summon a horse, some things have changed.

First `EntityHorse` is no longer used, the entity ID is now `horse`.  This also means that `Type` is no longer required.  The list of entity ID's that used to be covered by type are `horse`, `donkey`, `mule`, `zombie_horse` and `skeleton_horse`.

Currently `/summon horse [x] [y] [z] [dataTag]` is what you want to use.

The dataTag is where we can add health, color, tame, saddle, name, and attributes.

`{Tame:1}` will yield a tame horse.

`{Tame:1,SaddleItem:{id:"minecraft:saddle",Count:1}}` will yield a tame horse with a saddle.

`CustomName:"Example Name"` gives horse a name.

`Health:` summons a horse with the specified health .

`Variant` is used to select horse colors.

Your example of a brown horse with white spots and health of 14 would be:

```
/summon horse ~ ~ ~1 {Variant:771,Health:14}
```

The same horse only tame, with saddle, and named 'Charlie'

```
/summon horse ~ ~ ~1 {Variant:771,Health:14,CustomName:"Charlie",Tame:1,SaddleItem:{id:"minecraft:saddle",Count:1}}
```

[Here is the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Data_values) for a lot more information, including a variant chart for the different colors.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot choose a horse to any extent beyond a skeleton horse, a zombie horse or a normal horse. The normal horse can be a combination of different ranges of health, speed, color, and breed.